# Materials not correctly applying in MTLLoader

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have two separate models in which the first `model`'s material gets loaded with the material of the second. Below I'm loading two separate models and material files with OBJLoader and MTLLoader:

```
MTLLoader.setPath( 'models/' );
var url = "model.mtl";
MTLLoader.load( url, function one( materials ) {

    materials.preload();
    OBJLoader.setMaterials( materials );
    OBJLoader.setPath( 'models/' );
    OBJLoader.load( 'model.obj', function ( object ) {

        scene.add( object );
    });
  }); 

MTLLoader.setPath( 'models2/' );
var url2 = "model2.mtl";
MTLLoader.load( url2, function two( materials2 ) {

    materials2.preload();
    OBJLoader.setMaterials( materials2 );
    OBJLoader.setPath( 'models2/' );
    OBJLoader.load( 'model2.obj', function ( object ) {

        scene.add( object );
    });
  });
```

I'm not specifying texture paths because the .mtl files links has the paths already. I know I'm doing this incorrectly but I can't find any solution for this anywhere. Why doesn't my first model get applied the correct material? I just want to correctly apply the respective material to its model.

Comment: It seems `OBJLoader.setMaterials()` is overriding. Does anyone know a workaround for this?